# How to find the value of this determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant, multilinear-algebra

I'm wondering how to find the value of this determinant.

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  0&{{x_1}}&{{x_2}}&{{x_3}}& \ddots &{{x_n}} \\ 
  {{x_1}}&0&{{x_1}}&{{x_2}}&{{x_3}}& \ddots  \\ 
  {{x_2}}&{{x_1}}&0&{{x_1}}&{{x_2}}&{{x_3}} \\ 
  {{x_3}}&{{x_2}}&{{x_1}}&0&{{x_1}}&{{x_2}} \\ 
   \ddots &{{x_3}}&{{x_2}}&{{x_1}}&0&{{x_1}} \\ 
  {{x_n}}& \ddots &{{x_3}}&{{x_2}}&{{x_1}}&0 
\end{array}} \right]$$

I tried for some small $n$ and couldn't see any clue to find its value expressed by an easy formula. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this matrix $6 \times 6$ ? $\ \ \ (n=5)?$

Comment: Anyway, at Wolphram Alpha operation det[{{0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5},{x_1, 0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 },{x_2, x_1, 0,x_1,x_2,x_3 }, {x_3,x_2, x_1, 0,x_1,x_2  },{x_4, x_3,x_2, x_1, 0,x_1   },{x_5,x_4, x_3,x_2, x_1, 0 }}] doesn't provide easy to interpretation result.

Comment: see https://yutsumura.com/determinant-of-a-general-circulant-matrix/

Comment: This is a symmetric Toeplitz matrix. I am unaware of any closed formula for the determinant, but knowing your matrix has a name can possibly be of some help.

Comment: @Widawensen   you are right

Comment: @AleksasDomarkas As Jobe said, it seems that this is a symetric (additionally hollow) Toeplitz matrix.